# Что должно быть в gitignore для Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, git, gitignore

Создаю проект в *Visual Studio*, к корневую директорию проекта копирую `.gitignore` взятый [отсюда](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).

Под контроль версий я добавляю следующие файлы:

- Классы, Интерфейсы
- `.gitignore`

Собственно вопрос необходимо ли добавлять в систему контроля версий прочие файлы?

**Например:**

- `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`
- `Проект.csproj`
- `Имя_решения.sln`
- Прочие файлы

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не нужно добавлять `*.sln` в `.gitignore`. В файлах `sln` студия хранит структуру проекта и связи между элементами. Если вы будете потом откатываться к более раннему коммиту, то этим немало озадачите студию, ей придется заново выстраивать связи. Поэтому их нужно коммитить вместе с другими файлами.

На всякий случай оставлю тут копию текущего состояния [.gitignore с гитхаба](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore):

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# DNX
project.lock.json
artifacts/

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings 
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Windows Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
orleans.codegen.cs

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/
```

Comment: а как насчет папки `debug`? В ней лежат, насколько я помню, ненужные для коммита вещи: сам экзешник и еще какие-то мелочи

Comment: @whalemare в указаном .gitignore этот каталог уже в исключениях

Comment: @whalemare: ага, посмотрите на gitignore по ссылке

Comment: Проглядел, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Может быть будет кому полезен сервис для генерации `.gitignore` по языку, фрэймворку, IDE - https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: интересно как они генерируют, сравнил с тем что лежит на github, различия только в загаловке и двух пустых строках в конце файла

Comment: @Bald56rus ну скорей всего наделали шаблонов и потом просто добавляют их в результат по выбранным параметрам

Comment: Видимо, с гитхаба качают и вырезают заголовок.